# nodejs error on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, openshift, deployd

I am trying to run the following script on OpenShift SSH terminal

```
var deployd = require('deployd');

var server = deployd({
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
  env: 'production',
  db: {
    host: 'ds030607.mongolab.com',
    port: '30607',
    name: 'kheapdata',
    credentials: {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin'
    }
  }
});

server.listen();

server.on('listening', function() {
  console.log("Server is listening");
});

server.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  process.nextTick(function() { // Give the server a chance to return an error
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

like this node production.js but geting this error

{ [Error: listen EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'listen' }

Please me to resolve this issue.

here is the new script

```
  //production.js 
var deployd = require('deployd');

    var server = deployd({ 
// port: process.env.PORT || 5000, 
env: 'production', 
db: { host: '127.5.233.2', 
port: '27017', 
name: 'test', 
credentials: { username: 'admin', password: '4mA51PDYnL89' } } });

    server.listen('8080','127.5.233.1');

    server.on('listening', function() { console.log("Server is listening"); });

    server.on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); process.nextTick(function() { 
// Give the server a chance to return an error 
process.exit(); 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the wrong env variable `port: process.env.PORT || 5000`. Try sshing into your gear and run `env` to locate the right environment variable. Since it looks like you're trying to connect to mongo try running `env | grep -i mongo` in your gear.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to bind to process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP and process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, looks like your script is trying to bind to 0.0.0.0 which is not allowed, and possibly the wrong port also.  Also looks like you are connecting to an outside mongodb service, so you won't have any mongo environment variables in your gear.

Comment: I have tried NODJS_IP and PORT but nothing is working

Comment: ssh to your gear and run env | grep NODEJS and see what shows up, make sure you are using those specific environment variables.

Comment: I am using port and Ip in my script but still getting same error

Comment: Can you post your updated script then in your question, so we have the newest to test with?